# Execute Command with Karaf + SSH + Java

Tags: java, ssh, apache-karaf, karaf, sshd

I'm trying to connect to karaf from SSH from java (as shown in the documentation), the thing is, i am not able to execute any command from my java code.

What i'm trying to do is to  stop and start bundles from java.

i've already tried to use both createExecChannel and createShellChannel methods. But none of them works, im not sure im doing it right. i followed the doc to connect, but i cant find a good example (or something similar) of what i need to do.

this is what im trying:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ...
        SshClient client = null;
        try {
            client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
            client.start();
            ConnectFuture future = client.connect(user, host, port);
            future.await();
            ClientSession session = future.getSession();
            session.addPasswordIdentity(password);


            final ClientChannel channel = session.createShellChannel();
            channel.setOut(System.out);
            channel.setErr(System.err);
            channel.open();

            executeCommand(channel, "stop -f 44");

            List<ClientChannelEvent> evs = new ArrayList<ClientChannel.ClientChannelEvent>();
            evs.add(ClientChannelEvent.CLOSED);

            channel.waitFor(evs, 0);

            session.close(false);
            client.stop();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            ...
        } finally {
            ...
        }

    }
private static void executeCommand(final ClientChannel channel,
        final String command) throws IOException {
    final InputStream commandInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            command.getBytes());
    channel.setIn(new NoCloseInputStream(commandInput));
}
```

I don't get any error, but the commands dont execute.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you have, even if it doesn't work correctly. Describe how and where it fails. Include any error messages or exceptions that you get.

Comment: a "logout" command only close the current ssh connection. So the behavior you see looks like the expected behavior (ie - nothing!)

Comment: sorry for that, i left the logout command in there. it should be "stop -f [BUNDLE_ID]"

Comment: Please come to the Apache Karaf Mailinglist for such questions. And actually check if it's already been answered on that list.